# Export CoreData from iPhone and view it on a Mac?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm creating an iPhone application which depends on storing photos the user took into CoreData. I'm wondering 1) Is there a way to export the CoreData from my iPhone to my computer (so I can make back-ups of it) 2)Is there a way to view (and possibly edit) the CoreData containing all the photos on my Mac

Comment: do you mean you want to help any user of the app to do this, or just you for development/testing?

Comment: I just want to do this for development/testing? I'm creating a prototype and I want to store copies of the CoreData database and view it (and hopefully edit) on the computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,maybe its what you want.
https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger

Answer (score 0):

You can browse the contents of an iPhone like any disk using a program like this:

http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/

Comment: Where is CoreData located? Not the files written to the filesystem, but the DB used by the application.